# TailwindCSS ,Vite, and React compiles very slow

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, vite

My project is based on Tailwind CSS, Vite, and React. The Vite Dev Server is as it is. The browser takes too much time (more than 3 minutes) to render with Tailwind. HMR is extremely slow. Changes are not quickly reflected in the browser. In browser Style tab of inspect tool jams while trying to make changes. Even with JIT configuration in Tailwind, it no longer works.

Here is my tailwind.config.js

```
{
  mode: 'jit',
  content: ['./app/**/*.{html,js,jsx,ts,tsx}'],
  safelist: [
    {
      pattern: /./,
    },
  ],
 darkMode: 'class',
theme:{
extend:{...}
},
 plugins: [require('@tailwindcss/forms')],

}
```

Here is my postcss.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
};
```

Here is my vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  esbuild: {
    jsxFactory: 'h',
    jsxFragment: 'Fragment',
  },
});
```

Comment: Consider removing the `safelist` configuration – this is generating every single class available in Tailwind and seems like it could be a contributing factor to the slowness. Instead, rely on the JIT strategy that Tailwind CSS v3 uses.

Answer (score 0):

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
  }
};
```

just remove autoprefixer: {}, and also remove from package.json and package-lock.json